# Multiple if condtions in a single statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ecmascript-6, conditional-statements

I am trying to check if a `username` **and** `userId` exists **and** *either* a `like` or a `comment` exists then return something. And I am using two if conditions for this :

```
if (username && userID) {
  if (like || comment) {
    return something
  }
}
```

Is there any way to fit bot the conditions into one single statement. Also, here the username is immutable.

Comment: Another "and" with the "or" expression in parens? It might be helpful to check out some JS expression docs or tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

Just surround both conditions with brackets so you can group them with `&&`?

```
if (
  (username && userID) &&
  (like || comment)
) {
  return something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yup!

```
if (username && userID && (like || comment)) {
  // do stuff
}
```